# Behavior of Linux NVMe driver IRQ handler

Tags: linux, solid-state-drive, nvme

Good afternoon!
I'm looking at the linux kernel's design for NVMe driver.
As far as I understood, whenever interrupt raised by SSD controller, nvme_irq() function takes control.
Inside nvme_irq(), there is function named nvme_process_cq().
When I tested kernel trace with direct IO requests in sync, using FIO, there is some cases where nvme_irq() is called, but nothing useful done inside nvme_process_cq().
More specifically, inside nvme_process_cq(), there is function call nvme_handle_cqe(). And there is some cases where nvme_irq is called but nvme_handle_cqe is not handled.
I understood that no invocation of nvme_handle_cqe (because of returning false from nvme_read_cqe()) means that NVMe controller didn't append new element to CQ.
Then, my question is, why interrupt is raised in the first place?
I thought there is no need for raising interrupt if there is no jobs done in interrupt irq, as I described above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the kernel documentation [Linux NVMe feature and and quirk policy](https://docs.kernel.org/nvme/feature-and-quirk-policy.html) would be what you are looking for...